# Pass valuse from multiple blades to a single one

Tags: php, laravel

In my application in Laravel, i use to create multiple views.

In each view i calculate  a cost or something else. For that i use php, html tables and javascript to calculate the sum.

Anyway, What i need is to create a final view where all my results appear there and do some math with all the values.

I can't use @include because my encluded view got tables and buttons and other stuff.. 
The value i want to pick from each view looks like this:

```
    <div class="">Total Cash: <span id="totalbank" ></span></div>
```

Can someone help me to know how can i pick only this line to another view ?

Comment: This is a weird one. You should avoid doing calculations/logic on your view... That is what Services and Controllers are for... The view should mostly be responsible for rendering...

Comment: Data processed on the client side cannot be transferred between views without sending it to the server first. If you wanted, you could use ajax to pass in the data and load and append other views.